# Confirm Password Validator Not Working - Angular

Tags: angular

I have tried to make a custom validator. I want to add `ng-invalid` class (set input as invalid) if password does not match.

Here's the html-

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <label class="validations" @load *ngIf="!regForm.get('password').valid && regForm.get('password').touched">Please Enter a Valid Password!</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" minlength="6" required placeholder="Enter Your Team Password" formControlName="password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Confirm Password:</label>
      <label class="validations" @load *ngIf="(!(regForm.get('password').value == regForm.get('password_confirmation').value)) && regForm.get('password_confirmation').touched">Passwords do not Match!</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" 
          [ngClass]="{pwd_mismatch : !(regForm.get('password').value === regForm.get('password_confirmation').value) && regForm.get('password_confirmation').touched}" required placeholder="Re-Enter Your Team Password" formControlName="password_confirmation">
</div>
```

and component.ts -

```
passwordConfirm(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if (control.value != this.password) {
        control.hasError;
        return null;
    }
    return {'mismatch': true};
}
```

NOTE: `this.password` store input from password `FormControl`. 
`pwd_mismatch` class is added to the input in real time but not setting to invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is backwards. You must return null if the passwords match, i.e. if there is no error. So the code should be

```
passwordConfirm(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    if (control.value === this.password) {
        return null;
    }
    return { mismatch: true };
}
```

Comment: Okay now its fine, but ng-invalid is not removing even if same password is entered

Comment: Then this.password is probably not containing what you think it's containing. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Got it, Now i added-     if (control.value === this.regForm.get('password').value) but it cannot access get of undefined

Comment: I have this Control present in FormGroup-      'password_confirmation' : new FormControl(null, this.passwordConfirm.bind(this)),

Comment: Again, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.